Is the Frobenius power series solution valid for complex variable ($x=e^{i\;\theta}$ ) too?
Are we allowed to use the Frobenius power series solution for an ODE
$$ A(x) \;\Phi''(x)+B(x) \;\Phi'(x)+C(x)\; \Phi(x)=0$$
in which $x=e^{i\;\theta}$ is a complex unit circle?

In general, my question is: is the Frobenius power series solution valid for complex variables too?

